# Deploying drupal 9 on a remote server

Tags: 9, deployment

I've built my website on my local PC and I'm ready to go live and move it to the remote server.

I've bought a shared hosting package (so I can't run scripts etc, but I can copy the files over and export and import the database using phpmyadmin).

I couldn't for the life of me find a deployment guide for drupal 9, so to get things going, I tried something similar to what I've done for drupal 7 and have this structure on the remote server...

```
/public_html
    /config
    /synccomposer
    /vendor
    /web
```

So I can access the site at: `http://mysite.com/web`

But how do I set things up so that I can access the site at just `http://mysite.com` ?
I've tried moving the files in the web directory into `public_html`, and moving the other directories up one level, but that didnt work. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: `I've bought a shared hosting package` these usually come with C-Panel. All you gotta do is change the document root to `/public_html/web`, [see this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRB3kz87adQ&ab_channel=DomainRacer) for how to.

Comment: @NoSssweat thanks that worked perfectly

Comment: Since the question seems to be *I have a Drupal site that on local I access as `http://localhost/web`. How can I access it as `http://example.com/` when I deploy it on the production server?* it's not a Drupal-related question.

Comment: As side note, With Drupal 9 it's possible to have the *vendor* directory outside the server document directory and tell Drupal which directory is the server document directory. That requires changing how the development site is created, though.

Comment: @apaderno can you point me to a link or something where this is described?

Comment: It's described in [Using Composer to Install Drupal and Manage Dependencies](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies). [To do a modified install](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies#s-to-do-a-modified-install), in particular, says how the document root directory can be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing this through the .htaccess file, which you should have access to via the File Browser.  You may have to turn on the "Show hidden files" option tho.

Edit: Pointed out by apaderno, this is an incomplete answer.  To use RewriteCond, you do in fact need to combine Cond with RewriteRule. I updated the below with a more complete answer.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yourwebsite.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-name.com$
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1 [L]
```

Comment: `RewriteCond` is used in conjuction with `RewriteRule`; without the latter, the setting isn't complete.